# Unable to open TDMS file using nptdms package

Tags: python, python-3.x, labview

I have a TDMS file created using cRIO by NI and I'm using the python package `[nptdms][1]` to read it. I'm using Anaconda distribution of Python 3.7. When I use the following code:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile

tdms_file = TdmsFile("SN3595straingauges103-13-1908-39-49-AM.tdms")
```

I get the following warning--

> WARNING:nptdms.tdms:Last segment of file has unknown size, not attempting to read it

When I try to get the channel data using,
`channel = tdms_file.object("_unnamedTask<0>","Strain_0")`

I get the following error --

> File "C:\Users\mkha0010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py", line 157, in object
>       raise KeyError("Invalid object path: %s" % object_path)
>
> KeyError: 'Invalid object path: /'

Can you please tell me what's wrong? I've attached the file here as well. The TDMS file and my python script are kept in the same directory.

[SN3595straingauges103-13-1908-39-49-AM.zip](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/files/2965177/SN3595straingauges103-13-1908-39-49-AM.zip)

Comment: Which version of `nptdms` do you use? I guess this is known issue. Check this - https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/issues/14, and here it is said that it should be solved already - https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/issues/15#issuecomment-45685912.

Comment: I am using the latest version 0.13

Comment: The lates release is 0.12 - https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/releases/tag/0.12.0